# Xamarin Forms: Invoke a method in shared code from iOS custom renderer

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I am trying to figure out how to invoke a method in my view's code-behind on tap of a UIBarButton in my custom renderer.

Here is my custom renderer code from which I want to invoke:

```html
        protected void AddReturnButton()
        {
            var toolbar = new UIToolbar(new RectangleF(0.0f, 0.0f, 50.0f, 44.0f));

            UIBarButtonItem returnButton = new UIBarButtonItem();

            if (this.Element.ReturnType == ReturnType.Done)
            {
                returnButton = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, delegate
                {
                    this.Control.ResignFirstResponder();

                    var baseEntry = this.Element.GetType();

                    ((IEntryController)Element).SendCompleted();
                });
            }
            else if (this.Element.ReturnType == ReturnType.Next)
            {
                returnButton = new UIBarButtonItem("Next", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, delegate
                {
                    //NEED TO INVOKE FROM HERE
                    this.Control.ResignFirstResponder();

                    var baseEntry = this.Element.GetType();

                    ((IEntryController)Element).SendCompleted();
                });
            }

            toolbar.Items = new UIBarButtonItem[] { new UIBarButtonItem (UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace), returnButton };

            this.Control.InputAccessoryView = toolbar;
        }
```

Basically what I want to do is call a method in the view's code-behind so that when this 'Next' button is tapped another control gets focus.

Can someone please help?

Comment: use MessagingCenter

Comment: Can you be more specific about what's blocking you?  You're staring at the code and trying to figure it out.  What have you tried already and what did not work with what you tried?